# CSS not calling with cakephp syntax

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I wants to generate `CSS` tag with `CakePhp` syntax. My `HTML` is omitted successfully but
`CSS` not calling. i have put my css in  `app\webroot\css`.

below is my code. i am using these below syntax of CakePhp.

I am also using `DebugKit`. Hope it is not creating any issue.

```
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');

        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-responsive');
        echo $this->Html->css('admin');

        echo $this->fetch('meta');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');
```

**HTML**

```
  <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Dashboard :: Base Admin</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">    

<?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');

        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-responsive');
        echo $this->Html->css('admin');

        echo $this->fetch('meta');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');
            ?>
            <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">       
            <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
     </head>
```

**Controller**

```
class AdminsController extends AppController {
        var $helpers = array('Html','Form');
        public function index() {

        }
    }
```

**Result Coming**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dashboard :: Base Admin</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">    
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">       
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

Comment: seems quite unlikely that "html" (what's the name of this file?) is being loaded - you can check for this using the debug kit timer tab.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try re-downloading and extracting a fresh copy of cake, see if that's having the same issue, just to rule out that particular installation, or a PHP problem?